# WCF rest api does not show anything in browser

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am new to WCF and for creating a rest api service in WCF, I am following [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide) .

here is my contract code.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPayrollRest
{


    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "GET",  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "xml/{EmployeeId}")]
    string XMLData(string EmployeeId);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "GET",  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "json/{EmployeeId}")]
    string JSONData(string EmployeeId);



}
```

and implementation of this contract as follow

```
public string XMLData(string EmployeeId )
{
    return "Your EmployeeId " + EmployeeId;
}

public string JSONData(string EmployeeId)
{
    return "Your EmployeeId " + EmployeeId;
}
```

and my configuration for this service is as follow

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="PayrollService.Service1Behavior" name="PayrollService.Service1">
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="PayrollService.IService1">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost"/>
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="PayrollService.PayrollRestBehavior" name="PayrollService.PayrollRest">
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="PayrollService.IPayrollRest">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost"/>
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="PayrollService.Service1Behavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
                <behavior name="PayrollService.PayrollRestBehavior">

                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>

                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

when i run my code in web browser

```
**http://localhost:56140/PayrollRest.svc/xml/123**
```

nothing come up in browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use webHttpBinding as shown in the article.
I have tested it with the following configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="PayrollService.Service1Behavior"
                 behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
                      contract="PayrollService.IPayrollRest"
                      behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Service 'PayrollService.PayrollRest' has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element.

Comment: @rahularyansharma What is the namespace? Could you add a bit more of the files `IPayrollRest` and the one containing `XMLData`?

Comment: Its my fault. i done with that and its working for me . Thanks